# PHP: uploading text file to page, which shows new line for each text entry, and sorted alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, string-formatting, implode

I'm using PHP and I want to upload a text file, with the output / view showing each line from the text file on a new line (so exactly as it is displayed in the text file).

However, I also want the text file to be sorted alphabetically.

I have working code that uploads the file on each new line, and sorts by upper case, then lowercase - using the sort function

And I have code which sorts it alphabetically (regardless of case), but unfortunately the lines are grouped together, and not separated as I want them to be. - using the natcasesort

I've tried numerous things but not getting anywhere, so hoping someone can help either put the two together, or let me know what I need to do to either piece of code which will make each line show on a new line.

1st CODE NEEDS TO BE SORTED ALPHABETICALLY REGARDLESS OF UPPER/LOWERCASE
2nd CODE NEEDS TO SHOW THE LINE BREAKS

```
<?php
$file = file("users.txt");
sort($file);
for($i=0; $i<count($file); $i++)
    {
      $states = explode(",", $file[$i]);
      echo $states[0], $states[1],"<br />";
    }
?>


<?php
$filename="users.txt"; 
$lines = array();
$file = fopen($filename, "r");

while(!feof($file)) { 
    $lines[] = fgets($file,4096);
    } 
natcasesort($lines);
print_r($lines);
fclose ($file); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use

```
$text = implode("<br />", $lines);
echo $text
```

It would glue the array and pasting a `<br />` in every new line. Of course, if it is being printed in HTML, if not use the carrier `\n` instead.

And your code would look like:

```
.
.
.
while(!feof($file)) { 
    $lines[] = fgets($file,4096);
    } 
natcasesort($lines);
$text = implode("<br />", $lines);
print_r($text)
.
.
.
```

Comment: I tried replacing print_r as you've suggested. It comes back with error message: Warning: nl2br() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in....

Comment: sorry, I've edited it. Can you re-read my answer. At the beginning I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I dont really know how this works. How do I accept your answer? I thought I said the post was useful, but is there something else I should do now?